# find /path/ -ctime 1 what does it do? PERL

Tags: perl, ctime

find /path/ -ctime 1 or find /path/ -ctime -1

As a non native english speaker is hard to me to understand exactaly what this does.

I'm trying to find files that are older than n days and delete them after using

```
foreach my $l (@list){
 `rm $l`;
}
```

## NEW EDIT

what is going on here then? Why is it not removing the files?

```
my @a = `find /home/osboxes/Desktop/teste -ctime -1`;
print @a;

foreach my $l (@a){
 unlink $linha;
}
```

I have tried using the shell to rm the files:

`rm $linha;`

OUTPUT:

```
/home/osboxes/Desktop/teste
/home/osboxes/Desktop/teste/asdads
/home/osboxes/Desktop/teste/asdasdwqe
```

Comment: Don't use the backticks for removing files in Perl; the `unlink` function does it.  In fact, that loop should be written as `unlink @list;` which is compact, portable and fast.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I'm new to perl and i'm trying to learn the most i can.

Comment: I'm not clear whether the `find /path/ -ctime 1` code is meant to be Perl or shell?  As a shell command, it means "if the files (and directories) under `/path/` were last changed (for instance, change of owner or change of permissions — or change of content as that sets both mtime and ctime) within the last day, then print the file name".  That's a first approximation.  The `-1` means 'less than 1 day' (less than 86400 seconds ago) and `1` means exactly one day ago (between 86400 and 172800 seconds ago).  If you need to worry which way the conditions go on equality, look in the manual.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Could you take a look at the new edit? I'm having troubles with a function that i'm creating.

Comment: Use: `print "[[", $a[0], "]]\n";` and see what you get.  Then work out why you didn't get things removed.  The `unlink` function returns a status telling you whether it failed — it failed.  And please get rid of the loop unless you're going to report on the error for each file separately (which isn't a bad thing to do).  I don't think `unlink` will remove directories; there's `rmdir` for that.  (And if you want to remove empty directories, use `-depth` as an option to the `find` command.)

Comment: @BrunoFrancisco, in your edit, your loop variable is `$l`, but you are trying to unlink `$linha`. Plus Jonathan's hint.

Comment: @glennjackman in the real code i used the correct variable. I still don't get why it didn't work. I will try Jonanthan hint and i will come back to "report".

Comment: There's also the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) core module that could be used — it probably requires a bit more confidence in Perl than you currently have, but it is the correct way to go in the future.  Practice will make better; and it's Perl so TMTOWTDI – there's more than one way to do it!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you little bastard (don't take this the wrong way). I got it using chomp. I'm creating this function to remove backups older than n days. The unlink is the best option for me (i guess). Thank you for the hint. Have a nice day bro!

Comment: The important thing is to see how I helped you debug this.  Knowing how to debug (for example, print the data, and make sure you can see the start and end of what you're printing) is a very basic but very, very important technique.  Checking return statuses is an important programming technique.  Reporting errors when they're meaningful (and reporting errors so they are meaningful) is also an important user-interaction technique.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you. I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command is not in `perl`, it's in the shell.  In other words, it's a system command.  You can learn about it by reading [the find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

The `-ctime` test checks whether the file's status was changed before (+1) or after (-1) 1 day from today.  You can read more about `ctime` [here](http://www.unix.com/tips-and-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html).

Comment: The output of `find` will also contain the end-of-line character, which you would need to remove (see the `chomp` function) before calling `unlink`.